# Convert inputtext value to big decimal on jsf

Tags: jsf, converters

Whenever we use an inputtext for a decimal value, we do something like this:

```java
<h:inputText id="valMin" tabindex="4" required="false"
    maxlength="10" styleClass="valorMinimoMaximo"
    value="#{actionGeneralidadeUnidadeCalculo.valorMinimoTransiente}"
    size="10" label="ValorMinimo">
</h:inputText>
```

Where `valorMinimoTransiente` is a string and when it goes to the action, I convert it to a `BigDecimal`.

I do this because our decimal numbers have commas, instead of dots and when you try to convert something like

```
4,56
```

To `BigDecimal`, it gives an exception.

So, theres a way to get the `BigDecimal` value without this whole proccess?

*I'm running jsf 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.3 by the way.*

Answer (score 2):

Yikes!  Sounds like you're forced to use JSF 1.2 on an old app server, such as WebSphere Application Server v6.1.

You can use either the standard BigDecimalConverter:

```
<f:converter converterId="javax.faces.BigDecimal" />
```

However, you may find that converter to be limited, depending on your needs.  If so, then it's better to write your own custom converter.

So, read on for how you'd create your own converter class.

Create your converter class:

```
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter("bigDecimalConverter")
public class BigDecimalConverter implements Converter {
    ...override and implement the required interface methods here
}
```

To use your custom converter, you can use either:

```
<h:inputText value="#{someBean.field}" converter="bigDecimalConverter"/>
```

or:

```
<h:inputText value="#{someBean.field}">
    <f:converter converterId="bigDecimalConverter"/>
</h:inputText>
```

I haven't used JSF 1.2 in a very long time, but there's a chance that the annotation may be a JSF 2.0 convention.  If so, you'll have to register your custom converter the old-fashioned way: faces-config.xml:

```
<converter>
    <description>
        Some description here (optional)
    </description>
    <converter-id>bigDecimalConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>
        com.companyname.project.converters.BigDecimalConverter
    </converter-class>
</converter>
```

References:

[Java EE 5 BigDecimalConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/convert/BigDecimalConverter.html)

[Registering a Custom Converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaxe.html)

[Java EE 5 Standard Converters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnast.html)